# Generating data from non-standard function in r

Tags: r

I want to draw samples from this function

```
f(x) = 1/(gamma(1+1/x))^N
```

for x > 0 and N is  number of samples

I tried using the quantile , the rejection method and the metropolis Hasting but could not figure out. I'm also new to R programming.

**EDIT.**

The OP posted the following function in a comment.

```
Falp <- function(a, b, abi) {
    ti = seq(a, b, abi)
    m = length(x)
    Fx = fx = matrix(0, m)
    fx = 1/(((gamma(1 + 1/x))^N))
}
```

The formating was mine with help by `formatR::tidy_source()`.

Comment: As stated it is hard to respond with an answer. What distribution of `x` should we assume? `Unif(0,1)`? `rnorm`?

Comment: I don't understand your question; if `f(x)` is your pdf, then why is it a function of `N`? Can you please provide more details. Also: *"I tried using the quantile , the rejection method and the metropolis Hasting"*; please do share (some of) those codes and tell us where they fail.

Comment: A full conditional distribution, obtained from the posterior distribution. 
Here is what I have tried.

Falp <- function(a,b,abi){
  ti = seq(a,b,abi)
  m = length(x)
  Fx = fx= matrix(0,m)
  fx = 1/(((gamma(1+1/x))^N))
}

Comment: There are several things wrong in your function. 1) `ti` is never used. 2) `Fx = fx = etc` but `Fx` is never used and `fx` is rewritten in the next code line. 3) `x` is not defined. 4) Nor is `N`.

Comment: Oh, and `1/gamma(1 + 1/x)^N` would do the job, in your version there are too many parenthesis.